# How do I use a variable referencing an API in another directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using an API in my file `forecast.js`.

```
const url = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${weather_api_key}/${latitude},${longitude}`;
```

and I need to use it in another script called `http.js`. All I want is to run `node http.js`. My file structure looks like the following:

```
jspractice
- .gitignore
- weather-app
----- app.js
----- .env
- utils
----- forecast.js
- playground
----- http.js
```

Is there an easy way to access `url` and use it as `const apiURL = url` in my `http.js` script? Do I have to `npm install dotenv` into `playground` even though it was installed in `weather-app`? Thanks ahead.

forecast.js script

```js
const request = require('request');
require('dotenv').config();
const weather_api_key = process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY;

const forecast = (latitude, longitude, callback) => {
    
    const url = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${weather_api_key}/${latitude},${longitude}`;
    
    request({ url, json: true }, (error, { body }) => {
        if (error) {
            callback('Unable to connect to weather service!', undefined);
        } else if (body.error) {
            callback('Unable to find location.', undefined)
        } else {
            callback(undefined, body.daily.data[0].summary + ' It is currently ' + body.currently.temperature + ' degrees out. There is a ' + body.currently.precipProbability + '% chance of rain.');
        }
    });
}

module.exports = forecast;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export it from forecast.js using module.exports 
and import it in http.js using require.

Comment: What does that look like in the http.js script `const forecast = require('????./utils/forecast');`

Answer (score 0):

Your forecast.js must be like:

```
module.exports = {
  url: `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${weather_api_key}/${latitude},${longitude}`
};
```

and http.js:

```
const data = require('../utils/forecast');
console.log(data.url);
```

Comment: I am already exporting forecast for use in app.js as `module.exports = forecast`. Do I need also include the code above as a second export?

Comment: Please share your forecast.js file.

Comment: Just shared it above.

Comment: @ACH You are exporting a function.You have to call function and if you need you have to set return value.